# SQLAlchemy Model Circular Import

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models in the same module named `models`.  They are a 1-1 relationship and have been configured per the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one).

**Vehicle.py**

```
from models.AssetSetting import AssetSetting

class Vehicle(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'vehicles'

     vehicle_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     ...
     settings = relationship('AssetSetting', backref=backref('asset_settings'))
```

**AssetSetting.py**

```
from models.Vehicle import Vehicle

class AssetSetting(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'asset_settings'

     asset_alert_setting_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
     ...

     vehicle = relationship('vehicles', foreign_keys=Column(ForeignKey('vehicles.vehicle_id')))
```

If I use the string relationship building (i.e. `ForeignKey('vehicles.vehicle_id')`) I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: 
When initializing mapper Mapper|AssetSetting|asset_settings, expression 'vehicles' failed to locate a name ("name 'vehicles' is not defined"). 
If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'models.AssetSetting.AssetSetting'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

If I use the class mapping, I get the classic circular import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tracking_data_runner.py", line 7, in <module>
from models.Tracker import Tracker
File "/.../models/Tracker.py", line 5, in <module>
from models.Vehicle import Vehicle
File "/.../models/Vehicle.py", line 13, in <module>
from models.Tracker import Tracker
ImportError: cannot import name 'Tracker'
```

I believe I could fix this issue by putting the files in the same package but would prefer to keep them separate.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I discovered my problem was two fold:

1. I was referencing `Vehicles` improperly in my relationship.  It should be `relationship('Vehicle'` not `relationship('vehicles'`
2. Apparently it is improper to declare the FK inside the relationship as I did in **AssetSettings.py** (`foreign_keys=Column(ForeignKey('vehicles.vehicle_id'))`).  I had to declare the FK and then pass it in to the relationship.

My configurations look like this now:

**Vehicle.py**

```
class Vehicle(Base, IDiagnostable, IUsage, ITrackable):
    __tablename__ = 'vehicles'

    vehicle_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)_id = Column(Integer)
    settings = relationship('AssetSetting', backref=backref('asset_settings'))
```

**AssetSetting.py**

```
class AssetSetting(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'asset_settings'

    asset_alert_setting_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    vehicle_id = Column(ForeignKey('vehicles.vehicle_id'))

    vehicle = relationship('Vehicle', foreign_keys=vehicle_id)
```

Answer (score 20):

To avoid circular import errors, you should use *string relationship building*, but **both of your models have to use the same `Base`** - the same `declarative_base` instance. Instantiate your `Base` once and use it when initializing both `Vehicle` and `AssetSetting`.

Or, you may explicitly map the table names and classes to help mapper relate your models:

```
Base = declarative_base(class_registry={"vehicles": Vehicle, "asset_settings": AssetSetting})
```

Comment: about that class_registry dict explicit mapping, assuming Vehicle and AssetSetting will inherit this Base, wouldn't that be a circular import situation as well?

Answer (score 4):

Your `__tablename__` is referencing `vehicles` but your Foreign Key is referencing `vehicle.vehicle_id`

Comment: Sorry that was a copy/paste error on my part when writing the question.