Create an SQLAlchemy relationship between schemas without circular imports
I have models in two different schemas with a foreign key relationship like this.
File 1:
Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(schema="a"))

class Advertiser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'advertisers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    campaigns = relationship("Campaign", back_populates="advertiser")

File 2:
import file1

Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(schema="b"))

class Campaign(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'campaigns'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    advertiser_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(file1.Advertiser.id))
    advertiser = relationship(file1.Advertiser, back_populates="campaigns")

I want to be able to call Advertiser.campaigns to get a list of campaigns associated with this advertiser, but this call fails since schema a is not aware of the table Campaigns in schema b. I can't import Campaigns because that would create a circular relationship between the files. I can set Advertiser.campaigns in file2, but Advertiser.campaigns would fail unless I import file 2. How do I set up this relationship?

I had a go and failed so I'm also curious about the answer. I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421205/sqlalchemy-model-circular-import but it doesn't quite answer the question.

Did you get to try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74864195/how-do-i-create-relationships-across-different-schemas-in-sqlalchemy-orm, TLDR - do not specify schema in base, use one base, specify schema in __table_args__

I guess I have answered something similar before, this is close to your example.  Although I think it is probably better to directly reference the foreign key with a string than importing the ORM class and pulling the id off it because you probably will have more circular imports.
Also I'm not sure if forgetting the mixin just sets the schema to None which might generate accidental bugs.
./run.py
import os

from sqlalchemy.sql import (
    select,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    Session,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateSchema

from .shared import get_engine, Base

from .file1 import Advertiser
from .file2 import Campaign


def main():
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)

    with engine.begin() as conn:
        conn.execute(CreateSchema('a'))
        conn.execute(CreateSchema('b'))
        Base.metadata.create_all(conn)

        populate(conn)

        query(conn)

def query(conn):
    with Session(conn) as session:
        a1 = session.scalars(select(Advertiser).limit(1)).first()
        assert len(a1.campaigns) > 0


def populate(conn):
    with Session(conn) as session:
        a1 = Advertiser()
        session.add(a1)
        session.commit()
        c1 = Campaign(advertiser=a1)
        session.add(c1)
        session.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


./shared.py
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    declarative_base,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData


def get_engine(env):
    return create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}", echo=True)


shared_metadata = MetaData()


Base = declarative_base(metadata=shared_metadata)


./file1.py
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    relationship
)

from .shared import Base


class BaseA:
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'a'}


class Advertiser(Base, BaseA):
    __tablename__ = 'advertisers'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    campaigns = relationship("Campaign", back_populates="advertiser")


./file2.py
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    ForeignKey,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    relationship
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData, CreateSchema

from .shared import Base
from .file1 import Advertiser

class BaseB:
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'b'}


class Campaign(Base, BaseB):
    __tablename__ = 'campaigns'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # @NOTE: Using table name FK.
    advertiser_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Advertiser.id)) #"a.advertisers.id"
    advertiser = relationship('Advertiser', back_populates="campaigns")


